# Best way to use API in app that has limited use?

Tags: swift, api, server

My situation is that I am building an app (in swift) that pulls data from an API & displays them in a tableview (say for example up to 500 cells). The problem occurs with the API. It is limited to 200 calls/day and 6k/month, and one request is equal to 100 pieces of data, so to display 500 cells it would cost 5 call credits.

I am stuck on how to efficiently use this API. Currently, each time the user refreshes the tableview it will cost 5 credits. Therefore after this has been done 40 times, the API cap has been reached for the day.

The only solution I have though of is to have some script in js/ruby/python that pulls the data every x minutes or x hours and saves this to Firebase databse or firebase Cloud storage and then in my app I can pull the data from Firebase?

My other idea was to run the script on a server and pull the data from there.

Is there any other simpler alternatives that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent over consuming why not you run the API and save the results to your own DB; create a custom API specific for your app to pull from your personal storage and this way you can control the interval and frequency of how often you pull on the premium API.

You can setup a job to auto update your personal DB with the premium data every x amount of time, update new entries and add new ones as you see fit while on the client side they will pull the same premium data you’ve pulled; imo that would be how I would go about because without control you’ll find yourself facing a major scaling issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This sounds like the perfect solution to my problem! For creating my own database, am I correct in saying that first I should create a local DB on my PC for development purposes and then once I have my Api etc working like you said above I move to a hosting service like AWS or Google Cloud or Azure and host a DB there and save data there and configure my API to pull data from there for my app?

Comment: It doesn’t matter ultimately where as long as you can migrate to production freely; local, azure, sql, MySQL, AWS, etc; start off with creating storage and making a connection to it; create the tables and location for the data you need and write a simple read and write call to your premium API; write it to that DB and create an API to connect to that DB to get data flowing into your app; this way you can query as many times as you want without ever hitting the premium for every call :)

Comment: Just remember to build it in a way you can easily scale, you’ll have more power in your own DB and API as you can include different data points, calculation and logic; you can even call on it to display timelines, previously searched and viewed items and more without abusing the premium; build smart now so you won’t find yourself saying “man I should’ve did this before” a month or two from now :)

Comment: Oh one more thing you’ve mentioned you hit a cap of 40 per 24 hours; that’s an average of 2 calls an hour; use it wisely to populate your DB and essentially clone the data at your disposal and for user queries mention data is updated every X minutes/hours so if they query something you have yet to store locally you can queue their search term in a requests table of your DB; when you haven’t hit the cap and got queries available you can update the DB permanently with new data as new information is requested; just a thought & tip :)

Comment: Thanks for all the information, it has been a great deal of help and a lot to digest! I look forward to learning and creating my own DB/API :)